# Styling an Accordion Table

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

I made this accordion table using bootstrap accordion.  It works well, but it looks terrible.  The way I have it set up is a nested accordion.  the code can be seen as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
{% load staticfiles %}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- {# Load CSS and JavaScript #} -->

<!-- {# Load the tag library #} -->
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}

{% block javascript %}

<script>
//this is not working as yet
$(document).ready(function() {
//script to refresh div  - formclass  is class name of form
$('#formclass2').submit(function(event){
var servername = $('#servername').val();
var divname=servername+"div";
  $.ajax({
    url: 'formsubmitcode',
    type: 'post',
    dataType:'html',   //expect return data as html from server
   data: $('#formclass').serialize(),
   success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
      $('#'+divname).html(response);   //select the id and put the response in the html
    },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log('error(s):'+textStatus, errorThrown);
   }
 });
});
 });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var frm = $('#myform');
    frm.submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),  //picks up the action from form
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#test").html(data);
                $("MESSAGE-DIV").html("Something not working");
            },
            error: function(data) {
                $("#MESSAGE-DIV").html("Something went wrong!");
            }
        });
        ev.preventDefault();
    });
});

</script>

{% endblock %}

</head>

<body>

<ul>



{% for checkkey,checkvalue in orgnizedDicts.items %}


<div class="accordion text-left" id="accordion1">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1{{checkkey}}" href="#collapseOne{{checkkey}}">
      {{checkkey}}
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne{{checkkey}}" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">

        <!-- Here we insert another nested accordion -->

        {% for servkey,servvalue in checkvalue.items %}      

        <div class="accordion" id="accordion2{{servkey}}">
          <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2{{servkey}}" href="#collapseInnerOne{{servkey}}">
                {{servkey}} 
              </a>

            </div>


            <div id="collapseInnerOne{{servkey}}" class="accordion-body collapse">
              <div class="accordion-inner">

                  <!-- table row header -->
                  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                  <tr>
                  <th>Servicename</th>
                  <th>Curent status</th>
                  <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
                   {% for servicekey,servicevalue in servvalue.items %} 
                     <tr>

                     <td><input type="hidden" name="servername" value="{{servkey}}">
                     <input type="text" name="servicename" value="{{servicekey}}"></td>
                     <td>{{servicevalue}}</td><!--status-->
                     <td><input type="submit" value="Start" name="Start">
                     <input type="submit" value="Stop" name="Stop">
                     <input type="submit" value="Restart" name="Restart"</td>
                     <!-- </form> -->
                     <!-- </div> -->
                     <div id="MESSAGE-DIV"></div>
                     </tr>
                   {% endfor %}
                   </table>
               </div>

            </div>


          </div>
          </div>          

        <!-- Inner accordion ends here -->
         {% endfor %}


      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
{% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

It's part of a django project so I'm using their templating language to bring in the data to populate the table and generating it dynamically.  the data that I'm calling in is a nested dict nested within another dict. My table actually starts within the second nested accordion though.  On the nested collapsible part of the accordion I want to do some formatting but I'm a rookie with html and css and I just want to give the outter accordion a border and make it black with white text, and give the inner accordion a border and change make thm green. I also should probably change the buttons to bootstrap buttons but I think that's pretty easy.

Comment: I don't believe you'll get many solid responses, since it's really hard to look at your code and imagine the CSS that would work best. I'd recommend setting up a minimal HTML-only version at JSFiddle - here's a [starter template](https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/bootstrap) that includes bootstrap.